# Request Entity Too Large WCF REST Servcie

Tags: c#, rest, web-services, wcf

Hello  I am receiving "Request Entity Too Large" error, when uploading even small files of size **(188KB and 5 KB)**!. I added maxAllowedContentLength 
,maxBufferPoolSize
maxStringContentLength,
maxArrayLength,
maxBytesPerRead but still have the error – This is my config file.

Nothing of what I added seems to resolve the error.
I set the values of the parameters above to very large numbers.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Server=SHOUSHOUPC\SQL2016; Initial Catalog=db; User ID=sa; Password=123456; Connect Timeout=10000; pooling='true'; Max Pool Size=200"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
    <add key="HOST" value=""/>
    <add key="SID" value=""/>
    <add key="UserID" value=""/>
    <add key="Password" value=""/>
    <add key="CC" value=""/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" enableVersionHeader="false" maxRequestLength="2097151"/>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
    <sessionState timeout="2"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="MOH.MOHServices">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="webHttpServiceBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="MOH.IMOHServices" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpServiceBehavior">
          <!-- Important this is the behavior that makes a normal WCF service to REST based service-->
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="MOH.RestAuthorizationManager, MOH"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="16" maxConcurrentInstances="1000" maxConcurrentSessions="10"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <verbs>
          <add verb="OPTIONS" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="TRACE" allowed="false"/>
          <add verb="HEAD" allowed="false"/>
        </verbs>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000" maxUrl="4096" maxQueryString="9999999"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking"/>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </modules>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
        <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block"/>
        <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"/>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY"/>
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**The trace of the service:**

[image]

**The trace is showing the following message:**
The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Comment: try enabling logging to see what is the exact issue on the service

Comment: @mahlatse thank, but how to do it ?

Comment: there should be a few article on the internet, but the fastest would be to right click on your app.config file and select Edit WCF COnfiguration and look for the advanced Diagnostics Section,

Comment: @mahlatse please check the trace

Comment: What other error does it show instead of the Access Is Denied ( as this error could be a lot of things, you might also need to turn on other diagnostics options( e.g ServiceAuthorization - under Service Behaviours) and check what is causing the security error you are getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buddy, if you want to create the Restful style web service, we modify the webhttpbinding configuration by using webhttpbinding section instead of basichttpbinding section.

> ```
> <bindings>
>   <basicHttpBinding>
>     <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">
>       <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
>     </binding>
>   </basicHttpBinding>
> </bindings>
> ```

Here is a simplified configuration, which provided by the WCF4.0 new feature.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" name="httpbinding">
          <security mode="None">
          </security>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147473647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="webHttpBinding" scheme="http" bindingConfiguration="httpbinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Besides, the main reason is caused by the MaxReceivedMessageSize property, you can also just set this property.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: although  I figured it out myself and I added the webhttpbinding but I will accept it as an answer.. Thank you a lot.

Comment: I have one question , there is no need to configure any thing from the client app that is calling the service, right?

Comment: Theoretically, we need not set up related configuration on the client side, while I encounter some weird issue accidentally, which could be solved by configuring this on the client side.

Comment: I have not done any config on  the client side and all is working fine, is this normal?